split name on the basis of capital letter
I have a column named 'Name' which contains values like 'ViratKohli', 'RohitSharma', 'SureshRaina', 'ObedMcCoy'. How can I get it like 'Virat Kohli', 'Rohit Sharma', Suresh Raina', 'Obed McCoy'?
I tried
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1), -- First name
        ' ', -- Space
        SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE(' ', name) + 1) -- Last name
    ) AS full_name
FROM dim_players;

But it's not working.

A quick and dirty approach to achieve what you want could be this:
SELECT REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(?-i)[A-Z]+', ' $0', 2), '  ', ' ') FROM dim_players;

This probably isn't the most efficient solution but what you're trying to achieve is an operation I would choose to do in code, not something I would do in a query.
The REGEX_REPLACE function uses (?-i) to make pattern matching case-sensitive, [A-Z]+ checks for all uppercase characters. The matched uppercase characters will be replaced by a space and the matched character denoted by ' $0' essentially adding a space where you would expect.
The 2 argument in the REGEX_REPLACE function tells it to begin matching/replacing at the second character onwards, this makes it not add a space at the beginning of the string.
I wrapped that in REPLACE(..., '  ', ' ') to replace any double spaces with a single space just in case your names did have a space in there somehow.
Input:  BorisJohnson
Output: Boris Johnson

Input:  BorFis JJimson
Output: Bor Fis JJimson

If you want to separate all double uppercases so you get Bor Fis J Jimson instead then remove the + in the Regex so it's '(?-i)[A-Z]'.

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '([A-Z])', ' $0', 1, 2, 'c')) ... seems to be enough. We specify explicitly that 2nd occurence must be replaced and that the searching must be the case-sensitive. Also this variant is leading spaces-safe.
